# Keyclaok on K8S: not able to authenticate a user with username and password

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am integrating Keycloak with my springboot service, all deployed on GKE, I followed the installation instruction for Keycloak and all went good, when I tried to use REST API to authenticate an already created user using the below curl request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://<MY_KEYCLOAK_PUBLIC_IP>/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=demo-app' \
--data-urlencode 'username=test' \
--data-urlencode 'password=test' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=ee39b325-7dw4-4c0c-681f-29e2f7f63f57'
```

I got the below error

```
{"timestamp":"2021-07-03T20:20:23.570+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/"}
```

Knowing that everything is working so fine with the local deployment of keycloak, I think there is something wrong with `redirect URL` but not sure.

For the keycloak client configuration, find it below:

[image]

**EDIT:**

When I replaced the `Redirect URL` with `*` I got a different error:

```
{
    "error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://<KEYCLOACK_IP>/auth/*?error=invalid_request&error_description=Missing+parameter%3A+response_type"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `Direct Access Grant`, so you have to POST data to the token endpoint (not to the authorization endpoint):

```
curl -s -X POST \
  --data-urlencode "client_id=demo-app" \
  --data-urlencode "client_secret=ee39b325-7dw4-4c0c-681f-29e2f7f63f57" \
  --data-urlencode "username=test" \
  --data-urlencode "password=test" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
  http://<MY_KEYCLOAK_PUBLIC_IP>/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token
```